# NSString comparison not working in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have an issue with my `NSString` comparison method 'isEqualToString:'.  I have two (matching) strings that do not come back as `YES` when executing hte `isEqualToString:` method.

The code within the `if` statement is never executed. I also tried adding a `\n` to the `checkvalue` string in case there was a hidden control code in the text string.  At the bottom of the code are the variables showing in the debug window.

```
NSString *text = [dict objectForKey:TEXT_STR];

NSLog(@"%@", [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

NSString *checkvalue = @”OVERTEMP”;

NSLog(@"%@", [checkvalue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

if ( [text isEqualtoString:checkvalue] )

{
    // ... execute this code when the strings are equal
}
```

Here are the variable two values shown in the Debugger Window, followed by the string from the NSLog statement:

```
text=(…NSCFString *) @”OVERTEMP”

checkvalue=(…NSCFContstantString *) @”OVERTEMP”

NSLog output for text:  <4f564552 54454d50 00000000 00>

NSLog output for checkvalue:  <4f564552 54454d50>
```

Comment: Add an `NSLog` statement like this: `NSLog(@"text = \"%@\"", text);`. Make sure there is no space or other characters between the value and the quotes.

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@", [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` to your app. Copy the output and paste it into your question.

Comment: Transform them into a NSData to check if they are equal? It may point out a hidden character.

Comment: Here is the output using the NSLog the NSLog statement as shown:  text = "OVERTEMP

Comment: Rob, I added the NSLog statement (w/data encoding format) in my question above along with the corresponding output.  Looks like there are 5 NULL characters??  Any thoughts on best way to do my compare?  Clean up the text variable first?

Comment: @Frankd: Which one did you log (into `NSData`)? The second one has the same output?

Comment: Larme, in the 'Debug Window' shown above, I show the two variables as displayed by the XCode environment.  The third entry is the actual output from the NSLog method  for the variable named text.  I have since added a second NSLog of the variable named 'checkvalue'.  It has the same UTF8 string as text, except text has the 5 additional NULL characters (00) at the end.

Comment: From where did you get `[dict objectForKey:TEXT_STR]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `text` has some trailing NULs. You could trim them:

```
text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]];
```